# how to find packages that meta-package contains

Tags: ros, catkin, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I understand, ros is the meta-package that contains several packages, https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/indigo-devel/ros/package.xml, how do we not that which package does the ros contains?

```
k-okada@kokada-t430s:/opt/ros/hydro/share$ rospack depends ros
[rospack] Error: no such package ros
k-okada@kokada-t430s:/opt/ros/hydro/share$ rosstack depends ros
[rosstack] Error: no such package ros
k-okada@kokada-t430s:/opt/ros/hydro/share$ rospack depends roslib
catkin
rospack
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137216/how-to-find-packages-that-meta-package-contains/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-03-07**:
As a side note: metapackages are only valid dependencies of other metapackages. They are mostly a convenience for users when installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Metapackages are not supported by `rospack` / `rosstack`. Since metapackages are only meant for backward compatibility and convenient package installation for users there is no plan to add support for them.

As a workaround you can run something like this:

```
roscd ros
cat package.xml | grep "_depend"
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1